# condition LEFT JOIN with DISTINCT

Tags: mysql

```
select wyraz_id, count(wyraz_id) as c from worek w
group by wyraz_id order by c desc limit 11
```

This query gives me back top 11 favourited wyraz_id from table worek.

```
LEFT JOIN wyraz FROM wyrazy wy WHERE wy.wyraz_id = w.wyraz_id
```

The problem is, that wyraz_id in this case should apply to DISTINCT results only.

```
select wyraz_id, count(wyraz_id) as c from worek w
LEFT JOIN wyraz FROM wyrazy wy
WHERE wy.wyraz_id = w.wyraz_id Having distint(wyraz_id)???
group by wyraz_id order by c desc limit 11
```

I've managed to go around it by doing another query on the go, but seems pointless really if you can do all that with a simple join.

```
$d = $row['wyraz_id'];
"select wyraz from wyrazy where wyraz_id='{$d}'";
```

Thank you kindly for any suggestions.

Comment: select Distinct wyraz_id, ...

Comment: There is lot of confusions in the query. there is ambiguous wyraz_id. Please mention it correctly and your left join seems little confusing. How you can use FROM clause after left join.